# Getting SSL errors with nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've got a digitalocean droplet up and running, and the ip on my dashboard 159.xxx.xxx.xx, and with nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/hello_world I have this config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 159.xxx.xxx.xx;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /static/ {
    alias /root/dev/hello_world/staticfiles/;
  }
}
```

When I got to https://159.xxx.xxx.xx:80/ in my browser, I get this `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` in Firefox, and `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in Chrome.

This happens whether I have gunicorn running or not `gunicorn hello_world.wsgi --bind 127.0.0.1:8000`

Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to fix it?  Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: Have you tried connect to the 127.0.0.1:8000 with curl for example?

Answer (score 2):

You get an SSL protocol error because nginx is only serving HTTP on port 80, not HTTPS. But you mistyped https at the beginning of your URL.

Comment: Changing `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;` to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;` then  `sudo service nginx restart` I now get `Unable to connect` even with gunicorn running

Comment: When I go to `http://159.203.232.85:80` in the browser

Comment: within http host you can proxy to https without any problem

Comment: Can you not connect to your web server, or can it not connect to the downstream server?

Answer (score 1):

Start simple application on https

```
# gunicorn -w 4 --certfile=/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt --keyfile=/etc/pki/nginx/server.key test_app:app
2016-03-06 18:59:28 [8545] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2016-03-06 18:59:28 [8545] [INFO] Listening at: https://127.0.0.1:8000 (8545)
2016-03-06 18:59:28 [8545] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2016-03-06 18:59:28 [8550] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8550
2016-03-06 18:59:28 [8551] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8551
2016-03-06 18:59:28 [8552] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8552
2016-03-06 18:59:28 [8553] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8553
```

Configure nginx

```
server {
    listen *:8090;
    server_name www.example.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Test gunicorn

```
# curl -k https://127.0.0.1:8000/
Hello, World!
```

Test nginx

```
# curl http://www.example.net:8090/
Hello, World!
```

So I think you problem is with gunicorn application settings

Comment: when I curl nginx I get a bad gateway 502, not sure why i'm not seeing that in the browser, and when I curl gunicorn, I get `Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: what protocol are you using?